# exclude class names from breadcrumbs and leave only package names

Tags: python, python-sphinx, faker, autodoc

I am trying to imitate the behaviour that is shown in this documentation

https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/baseprovider.html

I have installed ReadTheDocs theme for Sphinx and also use autodoc extension.

My `index.rts` looks like this

```
  Contents
  --------

  .. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 4
     
     a_faker.faker.providers
```

`a_faker.faker.providers.rst` page looks like this

```
  Custom providers
  ======================================================

  .. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 4
     
     a_faker.faker.providers.person
     a_faker.faker.providers.transaction
```

and specific provider page looks like this

```
  faker.providers.person
  =================================================

  .. automodule:: a_faker.faker.providers.person
     :members:
     :undoc-members:
     :show-inheritance:
```

While the content of the page is fine, the end result is that it contains class names and methods on the left side of the page

[image]

How to exclude them? So that I would get only plain

```
Custom Providers
    faker.providers.person
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I set `html_theme_options`

```
html_theme_options = {"titles_only": True}
```

and it looks fine now

[image]